# AngularJS not interpolating values in data attributes

Tags: angularjs, interpolation

Why doesn't Angular interpolate values in data attributes?

eg:

this template:
`<img data-src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}.jpg" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}.jpg" title="{{photo.title}}" />`

renders this:
 `<img data-src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}.jpg" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3861/14472009669_e97c9a201a.jpg" title="DSC00319">`

Everything is interpolated but the data attribute.  I've seen a few other questions on this but not a good explanation as to why this behavior and what I ought to be doing instead.

I'm loading this route's module with the config below:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', function config( $stateProvider ) {
    $stateProvider.state( 'all', {
        url: '/all',
        templateUrl: 'src/app/all/all.tmpl.html',
        controller: 'all'
      });
}])
// Sample controller where service is being used
.controller('all', ['$scope', '$http', 'version', function ($scope, $http, version) {
        $scope.scopedAppVersion = version;
        $http.jsonp('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.people.getPublicPhotos&api_key=blahblah&user_id=57933175@N08&format=json&per_page=50&page=1&jsoncallback=JSON_CALLBACK')
        .success(function(data){
            $scope.photos = data.photos.photo;
        });
}]);
```

all.tmpl.html

`<li ng-repeat="photo in photos">
        <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/neptunian/{{photo.id}}/in/photostream/lightbox/" target="new">
            <img data-src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}.jpg" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/{{photo.server}}/{{photo.id}}_{{photo.secret}}.jpg" title="{{photo.title}}" />
        </a>
    </li>`

**UPDATE**
I think that 'data-src' is perhaps a reserved attribute for Angular.  Using 'data-blahblah' or any other attribute works fine.

Comment: Where is this in context to your controller declaration and what not? This should work

Comment: @tymeJV I modified my eg above with more info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried on jsfiddle, and there is a little mistake.

Use the **data-ng-src** instead of **data-src**. The directive is called **data-ng-src** or just **ng-src**.

```
<img data-ng-src="{{'http://www.w3schools.com/images/'+photo.img || ''}}" title="{{photo.title}}" />
```

or

```
<img data-ng-src="http://www.w3schools.com/images/{{photo.img}}" title="{{photo.title}}" />
```

Attribute differences:

- **data-src**: one of the data-* attributes that can be added to an element
- **src**: the usual for the url of img elements.
- **data-ng-src** or **ng-src**: angular evaluates the value and sets the src to the img element.

Comment: I am not sure this explains why it doesn't work with data-src.

Comment: data-src means nothing for AngularJS. The same as data-ASDF.